# YOLOR: RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

Tags: python, yolo

I am trying to use YOLOR on Google Colab, requirend dependencies have been installed properly and it also worked in the past. Now I am trying to resume a previous training but I get this error:

RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

I am using the following script:

```
`!python train.py --batch-size 8 --img 1024 1024 --data '../data.yaml' --cfg cfg/my.cfg --weights '/my.pt' --device 0 --name AeroDron_01 --hyp '/hyp.scratch.1280.yaml' --epochs 70`
```

I get the following error:

```
Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total   targets  img_size
  0% 0/350 [01:13<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/YOLOR/yolor/train.py", line 537, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer, wandb)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/YOLOR/yolor/train.py", line 288, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device), model)  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/YOLOR/yolor/utils/loss.py", line 66, in compute_loss
    tcls, tbox, indices, anchors = build_targets(p, targets, model)  # targets
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/YOLOR/yolor/utils/loss.py", line 148, in build_targets
    a, t = at[j], t.repeat(na, 1, 1)[j]  # filter
RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.